# Выполнение ps-скриптов с помощью веб-страницы

Tags: html, powershell

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, мне необходимо сделать веб-страничку, на которой будет несколько полей для заполнения. После заполнения полей и нажатия кнопки необходимо, чтобы с помощью powershell-скрипта были внесены изменения на сервер, используя данные из этих полей. Что для этого необходимо? HTML+ASP.NET+PS?

Comment: В любом случае все будет делать сервер. Веб страничка лишь посылает "сигнал" на то что бы сервер выполнил определенные действия.

Comment: Так а все таки, какие инструменты для  этого нужны? Что лучше использовать?

Comment: Технологий сейчас несчитаное множество. Как для начала можете использовать php + html

Comment: А зачем для этого веб-страничка? Что мешает написать функцию/модуль для PS, чтобы запустить, "заполнить несколько полей и нажать кнопочку"?

Comment: А вы уверенны, что вам нужен PowerShell? С запуском PowerShell на Web-сервере могут быть проблемы. Для этого может понадобиться дополнительная настройка, ибо веб-сервер работает как правило весьма изолированно и запуск PowerShell скриптов может быть запрещён из-за настроек безопасности. Лучше опишите вашу проблему. Что вы хотите этим достичь? Может быть, вы выбрали не самый верный путь решения проблемы?

Comment: @WalterNuss хотел сделать возможность создания учетных пользователей + несколько функций нужных мне

Comment: Тогда лучше используйте для этого не запуск PowerShell скриптов, а на прямую из C#.

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно делать такие сложные манипуляции с powershell, достаточно вам сохранить данные  в формат json(javascript object notation), которые позже будут отправляются на сервер(реализаций подобных систем много). Тогда сервер не привязан как какому-то конкретному языку программирования, так и к операционной системе.

Но если так надо именно через powershell, тогда понадобится visual studio 2015 + сервер на C#(webAPI). Там доступны переменные окружения powershell. Но у C# есть те же функции что и powershell и мое лично мнение, что данные манипуляции излишни + много мороки будет.

На вашем месте я бы поступил по разумному и сделал так, как описал в 1 методе